# apply ifelse() to each element of vector

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
a<-rnorm(100,0,1)
```

I would like to do the following:

1. generate a random number `rnorm(1)`
2. if the random number is smaller than a specified constant (e.g. 0.5), then add 1 to the `a[x]` if it is larger keep `a[x]`: `if (rnorm(1) < 0.5) a[x]+1 else a[x]`
3. do this for each element of a.

I was thinking of using ifelse()

`ifelse( rnorm(1)<0.5, a[x]+1, a[x])`, however, this only returns a single element as output.

I was also thinking of combining it with sapply:

`sapply(1:length(a), function(x) if(rnorm(1)<0.5) a[x]+1 else a[x])`, however, I'm not sure how to use if statements within `sapply()`.

Can someone help?

Update:

and what if instead of wanting to add 1 to a[x] I would like to add `a[x]+runif(1)`

```
ifelse(rnorm(length(a)<0.5, a[x]+runif(1), a[x])
```

this would add the same random number of each element of a[x] that satisfies the condition. is it possible to vectorize this second part?

Comment: You only perform one test in `ifelse`. You wanted `ifelse( rnorm(100)<0.5, a[x]+1, a[x])`, but Thomas is right. His answer will be quicker and more convenient.

Comment: Your `sapply` statement also works (but it’s more complicated than necessary, you should iterate over `a` directly, not over its indices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just `a + rbinom(100,1,.5)`?

If you need to use `ifelse`, the problem is you didn't vectorize your call to `rnorm`:

```
ifelse( rnorm(length(a))<0.5, a+1, a)
```

Comment: yes exactly, this is what I was looking for. however, in case I want to add a random number instead of 1 to a, it will add the same random number every time. is it also possible to vectorize the second part?

Comment: @user2733997 Sounds like you may want to play around with `rbinom`, which will allow you to add any number of random amounts.

Comment: would ifelse( rnorm(length(a))<0.5, a+runif(length(a)), a) work?